# Implementing a basic neural network to predict y = 2x

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

It's a linear function. I am giving the following input to it

```
input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

output = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38]
```

I learnt that without a hidden layer a network is just a perceptron and basically regression. But let's say after this I want to predict y = x^2 which would be non linear for similar output.

In tensorflow you can do

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import pathlib
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

print(tf.__version__)

xs = np.array([2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20, 22, 24, 26, 28])
ys = np.array([4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40, 44, 48, 52, 56])

model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=[1]),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1)
])


model.compile(loss='mse')
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs = 500)
print(model.predict([30, 31, 32, 33]))
```

I am trying to get my head on how a neural net started from scratch will work for same input length and same output length.

I am currently multiplying vector of input by random weight -> vector_h ( Doing in init function )

Here is what I started with:

```
import math        

def sigmoid_activation(x):
  try:
    return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))
  except:
    return 0

def sigmoid_derivative(self, x):
    return x * (1 - x)

class NeuralNet:
  def __init__(self, training_input, training_output, testing_input):
    self.training_input = training_input
    self.training_output = training_output
    self.testing_input = testing_input
    self.epoch = 100
    self.weight = [ random.uniform(0, 9) for i in range(len(training_input)) ]

  def neuron(self):
    return sigmoid_activation(sum([ self.training_input[i] * self.weight[i] for i in range(len(self.training_input)) ])) # I am not sure if this is correct.

  def run(self):
    for iteration in range(self.epoch):
      # Not sure how to go from here
      pass
```

A couple of questions

1. Is this more of a perceptron than a neural network?
2. I am using activation function so that when output is non linear function it can predict that approximately as well.
3. Do the shape of input given needs to be changed to be something like [[1], [2], [3]]

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly?